# There exist no ring homomorphism $\sigma$ between $\mathbb{Q}_3$ and $\mathbb{Q}_5$ with $\sigma(1)=1$.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, ring-homomorphism

There exist no ring homomorphism $\sigma$ between $\mathbb{Q}_3$ and $\mathbb{Q}_5$ with $\sigma(1)=1$.

Approach: Since $\sigma(1)=1$, we can conclude that $\sigma(q) = q$ for all $q \in \mathbb{Q}$. We have that $$1+3+3^2+3^3+... \to (1-3)^{-1}$$
in $\mathbb{Q}_3$. But this does not hold in $\mathbb{Q}_5$. Therefore there exist no such ring homomorphism. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(First, no, there is assumption of continuity, so convergence arguments are not directly relevant...)

Thinking in terms of Hensel's lemma, there will be different square roots (of rational integers) in the two $p$-adic fields. For example, exactly the rational integers $n=\pm 1\mod 5$ have square roots in $\mathbb Z/5$, and then, by Hensel's lemma, in $\mathbb Z_5\subset \mathbb Q_5$. Similarly, exactly the rational integers $n=1\mod 3$. (One should also note that a square root $\alpha$ in $\mathbb Z_p$ of a rational integer $n$ is *integral* over $\mathbb Z$, so is integral over $\mathbb Z_p$, so is in $\mathbb Z_p$ rather than $\mathbb Q_p$.)

Thus, for example, there is a $\sqrt{7}$ in $\mathbb Q_3$, but not in $\mathbb Q_5$. Oppositely, there is a $\sqrt{-1}$ in $\mathbb Q_5$, but not in $\mathbb Q_3$. So there can be no inclusion of either in the other (regardless of topologies).

Comment: Thanks! So the last part is since the polynomial $f(X)= X^2-7$ has a solution modulo $3$, but not modulo $5$, by hensel's lemma it follows that $\sqrt{7} \not \in \mathbb{Q}_5$ and $\sqrt{7} \in \mathbb{Q}_3$. Thus we have $7=\sigma(\sqrt{7})\sigma(\sqrt{7})$. So this implies $\sigma(\sqrt{7})= \sqrt{7}$. Contradiction, since $\sqrt{7} \not \in \mathbb{Q}_5$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that there is a square root of $7$ in $\mathbb Q_3$ begins with there being a square root of $7$ ($=1$) mod $3$, then Hensel's lemma.

Comment: Ok, I made an edit in my first comment. The last reasoning is also correct?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning in the edited comment is correct, especially if we note that a square root of $7$ in $\mathbb Q_p$ is _integral_ over $\mathbb Z$, hence over $\mathbb Z_p$, so lies in $\mathbb Z_p$, and thus can be mapped to $\mathbb Z_p/p \cong \mathbb Z/p$.

Answer (score 5):

No. The ring homomorphism need not be continuous with respect to the $3$- and $5$-adic (or any) topology.

Instead, look at the polynomial in $X^2 - 10$ in both fields. Use that $ℚ_5$ is the quotient field of the factorial ring $ℤ_5$ (in which $5$ is prime) and use Hensel on the polynomial in $ℚ_3$.

(Note that $ℚ_3$ is a field, so any such ring homomorphism $σ$ would be an embedding.)

Comment: Uhm. In $\mathbb{Q}_3$ we only have $2$-th roots of unity and in $\mathbb{Q}_5$ only $4$-th roots of unity, right?

Comment: @bob Urgh, yeah, right. With $p = 3$ this isn’t very useful …

Comment: Ah yes indeed, it's only $\pm 1$ in that case. And in $\mathbb{Q}_4$ only $\pm 1, \pm \sqrt{-1}$. But how does that prove that there exist no such ring homomorphism?

Comment: But that polynomial has  a solution in both p-adic fields, right?

Comment: @bob It doesn’t. This fact proves there is no ring homomorphism $ℚ_p → ℚ_{p'}$ whenever $p - 1$ does not divide $p' - 1$. About the polynomial: Well, I was hinting at $X^2 - 10$ being eisenstein in $ℤ_5$.